# How to generate URL per image in colorbox

Tags: javascript

I have a multiple image field that displays as a colorbox gallery. Is there a way to generate a URL per image? For example, if you click image 1, a unique URL will appear on the address bar, then another unique URL for image 2 and so on. This is so I can copy the URL and when I paste it on another browser or tab, the page loads and the particular image associated to that URL will pop up.

I have searched everywhere and did not find a solution for this. I hope to find the answer here! Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you are using the file_entity module all managed files (image, video, sound, document) have a unique path. You can even give it an alias as well using pathauto.

Comment: Hello! I'll explore this. Thanks so much! However, what I wanted to do is not simply create a unique path for each entity but open them up inside a colorbox automatically. The unique URL that I want should trigger the colorbox.

Comment: I am also having the same problem, How should I proceed?